# Improve performance of query fetching data from View

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I have a sql query which fetch only one record from View. My view is made up of lots of functions. It is returning about 60,000 records.
The topmost record that i want to fetch from this view is taking 8-9 sec.
How do i optimize my view so that it will take at most 1-2 sec.
Here is my view and sql query. Please help! Any suggestion will be appreciable. Thanks in advance.

```
CREATE View dbo.OMOrderPrePaymentINT    
As    

select   
   dbo.int_payment_customer_number_out('','OMOrderPaymentMasterINT',payment_id)  
   as customer_number,    
   dbo.int_customer_name_out('','OMOrderPaymentMasterINT',payment_id)     
   as customer_name,    
   dbo.int_FormatDate('','OMOrderPaymentMasterINT',document_date)      
   as payment_date,    
   dbo.int_payment_amount_out('','OMOrderPaymentMasterINT',document_amount)   
   as payment_amount,    
   dbo.int_checkbook_id_out('','OMOrderPaymentMasterINT',null)                         
   as checkbook_id,    
   dbo.int_cheque_number_out('','OMOrderPaymentMasterINT',payment_id)     
   as cheque_number,    
   dbo.int_cc_type_out ('','OMOrderPaymentMasterINT',payment_id)      
   as cc_type,    
   dbo.int_cc_number_out('','OMOrderPaymentMasterINT',payment_id)      
   as cc_number,    
   dbo.int_cc_authcode_out('','OMOrderPaymentMasterINT',payment_id)     
   as cc_authcode,    
   dbo.int_ach_account_type_out('','OMOrderPaymentMasterINT',payment_id)    
   as ach_account_type,    
   dbo.int_ach_account_number_out('','OMOrderPaymentMasterINT',payment_id)    
   as ach_account_number,    
   dbo.int_ach_authcode_out('','OMOrderPaymentMasterINT',payment_id)     
   as ach_authcode,    
   dbo.int_expiration_date_out('','OMOrderPaymentMasterINT',payment_id)    
   as creditcard_expiration_date,    
   dbo.int_order_payment_type_out('','OMOrderPaymentMasterINT',payment_id)          
   as payment_type,    
   dbo.int_payment_method_out('','OMOrderPaymentMasterINT',payment_id)     
   as payment_method,    
   dbo.int_erp_payment_action_out('','OMOrderPaymentMasterINT',null)     
   as [action],    
   dbo.int_modified_user_id_out('','',null)           
   as modified_user_id,    
   'NOT MAPPED'                  
   as void_date,    
   export_completed                 
   as exportcompleted,    
   dbo.int_ordergroup_id_out('','OMOrderPaymentMasterINT',payment_id)     
   as ordergroup_id,    
   'ECOM'                    
   as USRDEFND1,    
   dbo.int_ResponseToken_out('','OMOrderPaymentMasterINT',payment_id)     
   as USRDEFND4,    
   dbo.int_transaction_id_out('','OMOrderPaymentMasterINT',payment_id)     
   as USRDEFND5  
from PaymentLine 
where dbo.int_exportPayment(payment_id) = 1
```

**SQL QUERY**

```
select top 1  * 
from OMOrderPrePaymentINT 
where ordergroup_id = '943177C1-50B6-4E7C-A442-BA90CF2A03F6'     
order by payment_date desc
```

Answer (score 5):

Ouch.

User-defined functions are known to be [the worst performance offenders](http://sqlserverplanet.com/optimization/user-defined-functions-and-performance) in SQL server, and your view uses **a lot** of them. UDF's work in [row-by-row](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/rbar--row-by-agonizing-row/) mode, so it takes a while.

Try to replace as much of them as you can with inline SQL.

Answer (score 1):

What to the functions do that inline sql cannot? Each function call will use the query execution plan for that given function. If you use inline SQL in place of the function calls, one single overall (expected most efficient) query execution plan will be used.